# Is there an infinite number of primes of the form (5^n)-2 and/or (5^n)+2?

Tags: number-theory

I would like to know if there is a proof of this, that shows whether either one or both of the expressions: $5^n-2$ and $5^n+2$ will equal a prime number indefinitely.

(Is the set of values for (n) that makes those expressions equal a prime number, infinite?)

I was able to find only two big prime numbers of those forms (using primality testing websites)

$5^{1}+2 = 7$

$5^{17}+2 = 762,939,453,127$

$5^{2}-2 = 23$

$5^{14}-2 = 6,103,515,623$

Comment: Enclose your formulas in dollar signs and watch the magic happen.

Comment: Yua have left out $n = 3, n = 143, n = 261, n = 551, n = 2285$ for $5^n + 2$. And for $5^n - 2$ there are $n = 1, 26, 50, 126, 144, 260, \dots$.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Grumpy Parsnip!

Comment: And thanks Hans Engler, for adding those values! How did you find them? :D